# Will INFORMIX-SQL (isql) clients work with Windows-based IDS or SE engines?

Tags: informix

Can an ISQL Perform screen connect with IDS or SE installed on a Windows platform?.. If so, which versions of isql client are capable and supported?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ISQL has not been ported to Windows for quite some time (not this millennium, I believe), though it is still ported to Unix systems routinely.  Therefore, you are looking at 'old' versions of ISQL; I suspect that there is no supported version of ISQL for Windows.

Yes, ISQL can connect to either IDS or SE running on Windows.  There should be no problems unless you try to run Perform against a fragmented table (necessarily in IDS) created without the WITH ROWIDS clause.

Comment: If IDS and SE are supported on Windows, why wouldn't I4GL or ISQL also be supported on Windows?.. is it because they have no GUI's?.. How difficult would it be to port them to Windows?

Comment: Mainly 'no GUI'.  How difficult?  Difficult enough that it is unlikely to happen.  It was done before, so it could be done again, but the financial incentive needed to make it happen would have to be substantial (mega-dollars range).  There are a lot of rather Unix-specific assumptions in the code.

Comment: I've peeked at ISQL 4.10 for MS-DOS with an HXD hex editor, seen UNIX-specific stuff in it and seen how they worked around it to adapt to the DOS environment, memory management and all.. it didn't seem to be a difficult port for DOS.. sure would be nice if IBM made ISQL or I4GL open source, I mean its old enough to drink alcohol!